# What does "Error loading Python lib" ... "image not found error" mean when attempting to run Mac app created using pyinstaller?

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Python 3.9 on Mac Big Sur using most recent version of pyinstaller.

I have a functioning script name `Read_CSV_Barplot.py`, which I want to make into an .app using pyinstaller. When running pyinstaller, I receive some warnings but no error messages. Below is my .spec file, where I've modified pathex to include the directory site-packages where needed modules are stored. When attempting to run the resulting .app at the terminal I receive the following error message, which I'm trying to decipher:

```
Error loading Python lib '/Users/fishbacp/Desktop/dist/Read_CSV_Barplot.app/Contents/MacOS/Python': dlopen:
dlopen(/Users/fishbacp/Desktop/dist/Read_CSV_Barplot.app/Contents/MacOS/Python, 10): image not found
```

Here is the .spec file:

```
block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['Read_CSV_Barplot.py'],
         pathex=['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages', '/Users/fishbacp/Desktop'],
         binaries=[],
         datas=[],
         hiddenimports=[],
         hookspath=[],
         runtime_hooks=[],
         excludes=[],
         win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
         win_private_assemblies=False,
         cipher=block_cipher,
         noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      [],
      exclude_binaries=True,
      name='Read_CSV_Barplot',
      debug=False,
      bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
           a.binaries,
           a.zipfiles,
           a.datas,
           strip=False,
           upx=True,
           upx_exclude=[],
           name='Read_CSV_Barplot')

app = BUNDLE(exe,name='Read_CSV_Barplot.app',icon=None,bundle_identifier=None)
```

I've never encountered an error message of this type before, which is where my confusion lies.

Answer (score 1):

Based upon a post at https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/2047, I changed `exe` to `coll` within Bundle in my spec file.

When trying to run the new application, I encountered a different error message, "_tkinter could not be found." I corrected this using `brew install python-tk`

Things now work fine.